# PHP Function hebrev() explanation

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand the Hebrev function in PHP. 
https://php.net/manual/en/function.hebrevc.php

It say's: "Convert logical Hebrew text to visual text". But I don't understand the difference between logical Hebrew text and visual Hebrew text.

What's next is that the Official PHP Documentation doesn't come with a working example. So I wrote this code:

```
$hebrew_text = "בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.";

echo $hebrew_text;
echo '<br>';
echo hebrev($hebrew_text);
```

The output was:

```
בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.
.בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ
```

I see that the dot is reversed in the new string. Why?

Can someone point out the difference between logical hebrew text and visual hebrew text?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-visual-vs-logical

Answer (score 3):

Hebrew is read from right-to-left, meaning that the full-stop was moved to the left since that is where the sentence ends when read from right-to-left. This pretty much cleans the text up for reading purposes, rather than displaying it the way it is stored in memory.